# Using Gmail api in iframe PHP

Tags: php, iframe, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have implemented the gmail api in my laravel application to fetch the received emails from Gmail. To get the received emails from gmail it required to give permission to the email and for that it redirects to the gmail page of that email and when you allow it redirects to my application. Now the issue is my application is been used in iframe and in iframe when it does not redirect to the gmail page it give a kill page screen when tries to redirect. Does gmail api is not useful in the iframe or is there any setting I need to configure to use it in the iframe.

Thank you

Comment: please edit your question and include some code that shows how you are loading this in an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Gmail api doesn't support this is an 0auth2 design specification.

You cant redirect Auth in an iframe the user must be able to see the URL bar so that they can verify they are not being redirected to a fake google login and authorization screen.  While some auth servers will disable this Google does not.

Your going to have to open the auth in a new window or in a new browser tab on the users machine.